# How to normalized the normal distribution?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I am just confused how to normalized the Normal distribution. If a random variable $X\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, how to show that $(X-\mu)/\sigma\sim N(0,1)$?

---

I always used this result without a proof. We know that
$$
P(X\le x)=\int_{-\infty}^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}\exp(-(x-\mu)^2/\sigma^2)dx
$$

But Why $$P((X-\mu)/\sigma\le x)=\int_{-\infty}^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-x^2)dx$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your first formula with $t$ as the dummy variable of integration:
$$P(X\le x) = \int_{-\infty}^x\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\exp(-(t-\mu)^2/\sigma^2)dt\tag1
$$
Then $P((X-\mu)/\sigma\le x)$ is the same as $P(X\le \mu+\sigma x)$, so plugging into (1) this means
$$P((X-\mu)/\sigma\le x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\mu+\sigma x}\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\exp(-(t-\mu)^2/\sigma^2)dt\tag2.
$$ Now do a change of variables $y:=(t-\mu)/\sigma$ in the RHS of (2) and you should obtain your second formula.

Answer (score 0):

Use  (u) substitution from Calc 1/2 or whatever the class is called where you're from.

let $u = (x-\mu)/\sigma$.

$du = dx/\sigma$.

When you change the bounds, it is still - infinity to x (or u). Group the square root of sigma squared term with $dx$  and you can sub $du$. Then the inside of the exponential is simply the base substitution (factor the square out of both terms).

The left side becomes $P( X \leq \sigma u + \mu)$, solve for $u$.